# What is the purpose of using [-D_REENTRANT ] to compile thread program in c in Ubuntu?

Tags: gcc

> Use any editor to type your program and then compile it using thegcc compiler:
>
> ```
> $ gcc   t1.c –o t1 –lpthread [-D_REENTRANT]
> $ ./t1s
> Hello world!...
> ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601753/what-is-the-reentrant-flag

Comment: Identical question found at Stackoverflow: [Why do we write -D_REENTRANT while compiling C code using threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673370/why-do-we-write-d-reentrant-while-compiling-c-code-using-threads)

Comment: `-lpthread  -D_REENTRANT` is equivalent to `-pthread`

Comment: What does gcc -D_REENTRANT really do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120506/what-does-gcc-d-reentrant-really-do?fbclid=IwAR2h1sj22jum2qy7FwG1EntRB6QnK1gEhnzSE1Dx158xcwBBScCi9-A2Tmc

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/compile-4/index.html

> #### Defining _REENTRANT or _POSIX_C_SOURCE
>
> For POSIX behavior, compile applications with the -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE flag set >= 199506L. For Solaris behavior, compile multithreaded programs with the -D_REENTRANT flag. This applies to every module of an application.
>
> For mixed applications (for example, Solaris threads with POSIX semantics), compile with the -D_REENTRANT and -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS flags.
>
> To compile a single-threaded application, define neither the -D_REENTRANT nor the -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE flag. When these flags are not present, all the old definitions for errno, stdio, and so on, remain in effect.
>
> ---
>
> **Note -**
>
> Compile single-threaded applications, not linked with either of
>   the thread libraries (libthread.so.1 or libpthread.so.1), without the
>   -D_REENTRANT flag. This eliminates performance degradation incurred when macros, such as putc(3s), are converted into reentrant function
>   calls.
>
> ---
>
> To summarize, POSIX applications that define -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE get the POSIX 1003.1c semantics for the routines listed in Table 7-1. Applications that define only -D_REENTRANT get the Solaris semantics for these routines. Solaris applications that define -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS get the POSIX semantics for these routines, but can still use the Solaris threads interface.
>
> Applications that define both -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE and -D_REENTRANT get the POSIX semantics.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from the [libc 8.2 manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#Feature-Test-Macros):

> **Macro: _REENTRANT
>
>   Macro: _THREAD_SAFE**
>
> These macros are obsolete. They have the same effect as defining
>   _POSIX_C_SOURCE with the value 199506L.
>
> **Some very old C libraries required one of these macros to be defined
>   for basic functionality (e.g. getchar) to be thread-safe.**
>
> We recommend you use _GNU_SOURCE in new programs. If you don’t specify
>   the ‘-ansi’ option to GCC, or other conformance options such as
>   -std=c99, and don’t define any of these macros explicitly, the effect is the same as defining _DEFAULT_SOURCE to 1.
>
> When you define a feature test macro to request a larger class of
>   features, it is harmless to define in addition a feature test macro
>   for a subset of those features. For example, if you define
>   _POSIX_C_SOURCE, then defining _POSIX_SOURCE as well has no effect. Likewise, if you define _GNU_SOURCE, then defining either
>   _POSIX_SOURCE or _POSIX_C_SOURCE as well has no effect.